# WorkFlow Emailing

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I have a workflow that I want to email people once the form is approved or disapproved. It emails the the person that uploaded the file, which is the person in the CC section, but does not email the group I would like to have email when they approve or disapporve. Oh and on the site when I check for errors it says workflow completed with no errors.

The pictures is what I have going  on in my workflow.

[image]

Comment: When you look at the email the the CC user gets, what address is listed in the 'TO:' field?

Comment: The "TO:" section has the group that I would like for the email to be sent to...the CC works but the TO does not work. Which is weird.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: I did not publish the Workflow once I saved the Workflow. So, remember when you make changes to a Workflow make sure you press the punblish button on the top left hand corner in the ribbon.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using a column in a SharePoint list and the functionality of "workflow lookups".    I created a list "wfContactsList" with a "ccEmail column.  Note this needs to be in the same site collection as the list which will have the associated workflow.  In "CCEmail" column, you can have more than one email (which represents my group) by separating emails with a semi colon.   A bonus for me is that I can easily change out individuals in the cc group by editing my wfContactsList.   Hope that helps.